# How can I change HTACCESS to point to the subfolder where my project is

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a project in a subfolder of my xampp root (rootFolder/myProjectName).
Ok. But I'm using friendly URLs. So, whenever I want to link a JS or CSS file, for example, if I set:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script>
```

This is pointing to rootFolder/script.js not rootFolder/myProjectName/script.js!

Ok! I could add manually.. But, later, if I change my project to another folder or even to the root, I'd to change one by one!

How can I set the base folder of my project as "myProjectName" using htaccess (Or, if there is a better way..).

My htaccess is currently like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This is because I'm using the "index.php" to route! But there are some pages called outside (http://localhost/myProjectName/html/pageName) and I cant get scripts to find their way without setting "[src="**myProjectName/**script.js"] manually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can done it with the next way with VirtualDocumentRoot

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /path_to_rootFolder/%0

    <Directory /path_to_rootFolder>
            Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /path_to_logs/error_log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    # LogLevel debug

    LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
    CustomLog "/path_to_logs/access_log" vcommon
```

Then add domain name to your hosts file e.g. "test.loc". Create test folder in your rootFolder and Apache will looks to test folder. Also when you will need new project you can create new folder with another name and add new domain for it into your hosts file. But you domain name and folder name should be the same.